# Is there a way to add a variable to the clip-path url?

Tags: css, url

I'd like to give Clip-path Musemove Effects.
If it's a circle, you can give a var value like this in css

```
    clip-path: circle(40% at var(--x, 50%) var(--y, 50%));
```

But I don't know how to enter the var value if url goes in.

```
    clip-path: url(#heart);
```

Is there any workaround?

```
<script>
const htmlElem = document.documentElement;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMousemove);

function onDocumentMousemove(evt) {
htmlElem.style.setProperty('--x', `${evt.clientX}px`);
htmlElem.style.setProperty('--y', `${evt.clientY}px`);
}
</script>
```

jsfiddle
[In the case of circle - It's working.](https://jsfiddle.net/jwpg018241/rh4q7mbf/15/)

jsfiddle
[In the case of url - It's not working.](https://jsfiddle.net/jwpg018241/rh4q7mbf/16/)

Comment: Could you explain what you want to happen on mousemove. Do you just want the clipped element to be repositioned to the mouse position? Please provide the relevant JS, HTML and css you have so far.

Comment: I attached the jsfiddle url. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SVG as mask instead.

```js
const htmlElem = document.documentElement;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMousemove);

function onDocumentMousemove(evt) {
  htmlElem.style.setProperty('--x', `${evt.clientX - 100}px`);
  htmlElem.style.setProperty('--y', `${evt.clientY - 100}px`);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Monaco;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  --m: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M42 27v-20c0-3.7-3.3-7-7-7s-7 3.3-7 7v21l12 15-7 15.7c14.5 13.9 35 2.8 35-13.7 0-13.3-13.4-21.8-26-18zm6 25c-3.9 0-7-3.1-7-7s3.1-7 7-7 7 3.1 7 7-3.1 7-7 7z" /></svg>' ) ;
  -webkit-mask: var(--m) var(--x, 50%) var(--y, 50%) no-repeat;
          mask: var(--m) var(--x, 50%) var(--y, 50%) no-repeat;
  background-color: blue;
}

img {
 max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.typotheque.com/ssadmin/assets/FontImageGenerator/AaImage29.png">
</div>
```